# I used response=requests.post("<url>",data={'key':'<API key>'})but the output says Unrecognized token 'key': was expecting ('true','false'or'null

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

Here is the code I used:

```
import requests
data={'key':'eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJtYWlsSxyxylbnRpdHk.....ZGtoYW4xNjIwMDBAZ21haWwuY29tIn0.RumJjxNP9_E2vCTkayKc0btm50ggeTGw5ICv7bsktv4'}
response=requests.post('https://data.geoiq.io/dataapis/v1.0/covid/availabledistricts',data)
print(response)
print(response.content)
```

This is tthe output I am getting:

```
<Response [400]>
b'{"message": "Could not parse request body into json: Unrecognized token \\\'key\\\': was expecting (\\\'true\\\', \\\'false\\\' or \\\'null\\\')\\n at [Source: (byte[])\\"key=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJtYWlsSWRlbnRpdHk.....WhhZGtoYW4xNjIwMDBAZ21haWwuY29tIn0.RumJjxNP9_E2vCTkayKc0btm50ggeTGw5ICv7bsktv4\\"; line: 1, column: 5]"}'
```

(I have changed the API KEY deliberately)

Answer (score 0):

Don't put the data directly, but use:

```
import json
response=requests.post('https://data.geoiq.io/dataapis/v1.0/covid/availabledistricts',json.dumps(data))
```

Comment: or just use the JSON support built into requests by doing `requests.post(url, json=data)`